# MongoDB Booleans

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In MongoDB, I could store a boolean like so:

```
active: True
```

But that doesn't really take advantage of NoSQL, since there's no reason to have the active property at all if it's false. Is there a way to have a property with whose only characteristic is being set or unset? A property without a value, or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB's dynamic schema supports different fields for documents within the same collection, so there is no strict requirement for all documents to have an `active` field. The main consideration here will be how that affects your application logic; it may be simpler to have an explicit field present and check the value.

If you have an index on a field, documents that do not have that field present will have a `null` value included in the index by default. This can potentially be useful if you want to save some bytes of storage by assuming that missing values are `false`.

If it only makes sense to store a `true` value for your use case (and you do not want to search on `false` values), you can:

- `$set` the `active` field to indicate `true` values
- [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) the `active` field to indicate `false` values
- use a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) so only the documents with a value present are indexed

If you need to query on both `true` and `false` values of `active`, you would be better using a normal (non-sparse) index.

Notes:

- You can use the [`$exists` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to match documents where a field does (or does not) exist.
- FAQ: [How do I query for fields that have `null` values?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-query-for-fields-that-have-null-values)